# How can __len__ check type of output despite being overridden?

Tags: python

The `__len__/__repr__` methods make sure that the output is always int/str even when I override them.

My question is: 
How can I **inherit** a functionality around a method of a **subclass**? 
(just like I can override `__len__` but it still checks that the output is integer?)

For example, even if overridden, `__len_` still does something like this:

```
def __len__(self):
   out = ...
   assert type(out) == int
   return out
```

Comment: You don't.  It's for subclass to override behavior of parent, and it's none of parent class business about that...

Comment: No, `__len__` doesn't do that, but `len` does. Those are two different, but related things

Comment: You can't do *exactly* this, but the usual thing is to expose a method that users of the class use, and then another method that the child class overrides. The former calls the latter, and can do whatever it wants to validate the result. (As others have pointed out, this is essentially what is happening here, with the built-in `len()` instead of another method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, and `__len__()` doesn't, the trick here is you don't call `__len__()` directly, you call `len()` which then calls `__len__()`, as pointed out in 
[kaya3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59079467/722121).

You can, however, repeat this pattern to do a similar thing in your code. Provide a method the user should override, and then another one that calls that method and validates it as necessary for end-users of the type to call.

E.g:

```
class SomeClass(ABC):
    def do_something(self):
        """Call to do something."""
        result = do_something_unsafe()
        if validate(result):
            return result
        else:
            raise ...

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something_unsafe(self):
        """Override me in subclasses."""
        return ...
```

Of course, if it makes sense in your API, you could also follow the given example use a top-level function, which is less likely to be overridden by mistake.

Comment: I like this answer, because it shows the behaviour as a pattern that can be adopted in one's own code; +1. I think `do_something` should still be a function (like `len` and `str`) rather than a method, though, so it can't be overridden accidentally.

Comment: @kaya3 "Can't be" is a bit strong—you can always just assign over the top of that function, but I agree that this does present more opportunity for a user to incorrectly override the wrong method by mistake. I would argue that the more important thing is if a module-level function makes sense for the API you are going for.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. The difference is in what the code communicates; most programmers know it's usually wrong to reassign an existing global name, whereas overriding a method is generally not expected to be a mistake.

Comment: @kaya3 Agreed. As another potential factor: it could also be valid to allow the implementing class to override the validation too in some cases, so it really comes down to what works best in the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The `__len__` and `__str__` methods don't do this, as demonstrated below:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 'foo'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 22
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__len__()
'foo'
>>> a.__str__()
22
```

It is the `len` and `str` functions which check it:

```py
>>> len(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> str(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

So the answer is simple: those functions are built-in in Python, and they are written to check the type returned by the `__len__` and `__str__` methods before passing those return values on.